# AdSense Management API - Missing required parameter: redirect_uri With Service Account

Tags: php, google-oauth, adsense-api

I am getting the following Error when trying to connect with the AdSense Management API Example:

> Missing required parameter: redirect_uri

I am using a service Account, because my Server handles all the interaction between the adSense api. The user is not involved. Here is my PHP Code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("PeopleHelpingPeople"); // name of your app

// set assertion credentials
$client->setAssertionCredentials(
  new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    "...", 
array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
file_get_contents('client_data.json')  // keyfile you downloaded
));
$client->setScopes(array(
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
));
$client->setClientId("...");           // from API console
$client->setAccessType('offline_access');  // this may be unnecessary?

// Create service.
$service = new Google_Service_AdSense($client);
```

Why am I getting this Error?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use a ServiceAccount from the developers console, the kind of account that gives you a p12 file, those will not work with Adsense.

Take a look at the note on this page https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/getting_started

$client->setRedirectUri() may get you past this error but it wont solve your ultimate issue